# "Invalid format is malformed at" exception while using Joda time

Tags: java, jodatime

Joda time throws exception as:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "23-Apr-2020
>   10:35:06 AM UTC" is malformed at "-Apr-2020 10:35:06 AM UTC"  at
>   org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:873)
>     at org.joda.time.DateTime.parse(DateTime.java:144)  at
>   org.joda.time.DateTime.parse(DateTime.java:133)

The line of code causing this exception is:

```
public static DateTimeFormatter LicenseFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a z").withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
DateTime webDate = DateTime.parse(DateTime.now().toString(LicenseFormat));
```

I am not able to trace down the issue, the date "23-Apr-2020 10:35:06 AM UTC" is in correct format of "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a z" then why it's throwing exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh very minor issue, I should pass second argument to method `parse()` of type `DateTimeFormatter`.

As:

`DateTime webDate = DateTime.parse(DateTime.now().toString(LicenseFormat), LicenseFormat);`